# Javascript blocking css?

Tags: javascript, css, image, xmlhttprequest, blocking

I have a lightbox photo gallery I am building. When the first image loads the css transition works. When every image after loads it does not. Any ideas why? The photos after the first one load but they have no transition.

```js
Image.prototype.load = function(url){
          var thisImg = this;
          var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlHTTP.open('GET', url,true);
          xmlHTTP.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
          xmlHTTP.onload = function(e) {
              var blob = new Blob([this.response]);
              thisImg.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          };
          xmlHTTP.onprogress = function(e) {
              thisImg.completedPercentage = parseInt((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
          };
          xmlHTTP.onloadstart = function() {
              thisImg.completedPercentage = 0;
          };
          xmlHTTP.onloadend = function() {
              thisImg.completedPercentage = 0;
              gallery.appendChild(currentImage);
              gallery.className = "gallery toggle";
          };
          xmlHTTP.send();
        };
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.gallery.toggle {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: You can refer https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS#InlineJS

Answer (score 0):

your CSS is executed on page load. When you dynamically add or remove content, CSS is not loaded again. You would probably have to create the transitions with JS after loading the image.

Maybe this helps:

https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the images with the class `gallery toggle`, which means the transition will never take place; it will be loaded in its final state. You need to load the images with `gallery`, allow the DOM to render, and then add the `toggle` class. You can probably get it working by doing this:

```
xmlHTTP.onloadend = function() {
    thisImg.completedPercentage = 0;
    gallery.appendChild(currentImage);
    gallery.className = "gallery";

    setTimeout(function () {
        gallery.className = 'gallery toggle';
    }, 20);
};
```